# Django didn't apply new modifications

Tags: django, deployment

I deployed my Django app, then I edit the source code, but my edits didn't applied.

example:

```
class Type(models.Model):
    seller          = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name="cam_seller_profile", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    label           = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    slug            = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "test"
```

the new update:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return self.seller.user.username
```

result still the same as old

[image]

I tried this to reload nginx but didn't work:

```
service nginx reload
sudo systemctl restart nginx
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved by reloading Supervisor

```
supervisorctl restart myproject
```

source : https://rahmonov.me/posts/run-a-django-app-with-nginx-gunicorn-and-supervisor/